# How to create a button that extracts data from a query in Access 2010?

Tags: database, ms-access

I work for a private healthcare organisation which provides healthcare to other organisations. I have an Access database that will allow a user to view all the healthcare we have provided to a specific client. For example, Company A - we have provided their staff with a vaccine etc.

What I need to know is how do I create a button on a form which will allow me to extract data from one of my queries?

In this case, I want the button 'Extract Data' to retrieve information from my 'Customer_Name' query (unable to post picture as I don't have enough reputation).

I've tried using the Wizard that opens when you create a button, but I guess i'm not selecting the right option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is create the query which will provide the exact extract that you need.  Since you haven't given much information in that regard, I will assume you have created this query already.

The next thing you need to do is determine whether you want to display this on a form or in a report.  If it's on a form, you need to decide whether you want to make it a "Continuous Form" or not.  A "Continuous Form" allows you to see multiple records simultaneously, while a standard form does not.  Add the query you've created above as your form or report's RecordSource.

Once you have created your form or report, all you need to do is create a button to open the form or report.  For this, you would add a new button using the wizard, choose either "Form Operations" or "Report Operations" and the appropriate "Open" option under that.  Then you select the form or report you want to display.